# How to alias pip to pip3 while using sudo for a specific user?

Tags: python, python3, pip, alias, su

I have python2 and python3 both installed on Ubuntu 16.04, and use python3 primarily. I have both `pip` and `python` aliased to `pip3` and `python3`, respectively, in my user's `.bashrc`.

However, I had always gotten funky interactions with pip while installing new packages, and now I find out why: when I `sudo pip install whatever`, the alias in `.bashrc` is no longer applied to the superuser.

Supposing this computer isn't mine alone and other users might log in and want to use python2 primarily, how can I set it up so that for my user only can use `sudo pip` to install python3 packages?

Answer (score 2):

`sudo` resets environment with secure path, so you don't get user environments when using `sudo` command. You can use `sudo python3 -m ModuleName` to run a module with python3, for example

```
arryph@localhost:~$ sudo python3 -m pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (python 3.5)
```